# Missing figure description in a ACM template in Overleaf

Tags: acm

I'm using a ACM template but whenever I use \description the text I write doesn't show up. Same with adding a description to a table. The only thing that works is \caption

I also tried using \small and writing my image text there but the formatting is not in justify

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please add a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805) to your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct behavior.  The text in `\description` is intended for adding clues for a screen reader (computer program) to make your figures understandable to blind and visually impaired people.  It is not normally typeset.